Is there a name for higher order angles and their measures?
It's well known that radians are a measure of angles that simply measure the length of the arc formed by that angle on a unit circle. I see no reason why this couldn't be generalised to higher dimensions: you could measure the $\underline{\hspace{3cm}}$ (insert name here) at a vertex of a polyhedron by measuring the area where the tangent cone, at the vertex, intersects the unit sphere, centred at that vertex. Naturally, the Lebesgue measure could be used for dimensions higher still.
My questions are these:

Is there a name, in any branch of geometry, for this kind of higher-dimensional dimensionless angle?
Is there a name for the generalisation of radians, as described above, for measuring these things?

